# "$" pass in shell exec

Tags: php, linux, passwords

I am trying to write an application for Linux system user change password.

Here is the code for that:

`shell_exec("/usr/bin/passwd ".$user." <<EOF\n".$password."\n".$password."\nEOF");`

It take all the spacial characters accept  "$"

How to pass "$" in shell_exec?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you can escape it using `\$` or include your string content inside single quote. as single quotes doesn't expand variables

```
shell_exec('/usr/bin/passwd $'.$user." <<EOF\n".$password."\n".$password."\nEOF");
```

alternatively you can also pass the command string to `shellescapearg` as follows

```
$arg = $user." <<EOF\n".$password."\n".$password."\nEOF";
shell_exec('usr/bin/passwd ' . $arg);
```

Comment: `shell_exec('/usr/bin/passwd $'.$user." <<EOF\n".$password."\n".$password."\nEOF");` It doesn't work.

Comment: what doesn't work? are you trying to change the password of a user, then your missing the current password,

Comment: Try to change the Linux user password with $password="test$123" and then check

Comment: ah your variable has a $ value

Comment: Yes my variable has $

Comment: so only for $ I have to pass other special characters are work without "\" eg : "!@#%^&*" all are working without pass "\"

Comment: Well that is the specialchar %^&* doesn't really have special meaning inside strings

Comment: can you give me the example of  escapeshellarg ?

Comment: It is still not allowed "$" character.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the error is related to the `$` symbol. A code similar to yours worked just fine for me.

I used the following to test:

```
$msg = "Hello world"; shell_exec("notify-send ".$msg);
```

Comment: Try to change the Linux user password with $password="test$123" and then check

Comment: Not sure I  understood what you've said but this: `$msg = "Hello$ world"; shell_exec("notify-send ".$msg);` worked.

Comment: I have tried the following script: `$user ='test';
$pass = 'test$a';
echo $pass;
$arg = $user." <<EOF\n".$pass."\n".$pass."\nEOF";   
shell_exec('/usr/bin/passwd ' . $arg);`    But won't work.